# & and &amp: sign not picking up in Wordpress

Tags: wordpress

I installed a colorbox plugin so I can place videos in a popup within the same page. When I add a video like this in my file in the Wordpress Editor

```
<a href="https://www.youtube.com/embed/xT24Q36teqc?rel=0&wmode=transparent" class="youtube">
</a>
```

In google chrome the link is cut off right after rel=0
I figured this was due to the ampersand but both & and &amp: wont work and the url in Inspect Element on Google chrome looks like this

```
<a href="https://www.youtube.com/embed/xT24Q36teqc?rel=0" class="youtube">
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I seemed to fix it by removing the embed/ part. The plugin for the popup kept adding an extra /embed/ into the link url. Thanks for your answer though!

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing & with its URI encoded value %26

```
<a href="https://www.youtube.com/embed/xT24Q36teqc?rel=0%26wmode=transparent" class="youtube">
</a>
```

Comment: If I do it that way it still doesnt work. URI encoded value wont translate to an ampersand